# Troubleshooting issues on forums, how safe is it?

Tags: linux, security

I was wondering if you could tell me how dangerous it might get to post (on some major Linux forums) outputs of commands like `lshw`, `lsusb`, `lspci` or `dmesg` publicly in order to solve some hardware problems.

`lshwd` - lists hardware and appropriate modules

`lsusb` - is a utility for displaying information about USB buses in the system and the devices connected to them

`lspci` - is a utility for displaying information about PCI buses in the system and devices connected to them

`dmesg` - The program helps users to print out their boot up messages

Here are some specific concerns I have:

1. Can you be compromised posting outputs of aforementioned?
2. Do you need to apply some filters and not dumping everything that Terminal brings out?
3. Are there any dangerous commands that one should avoid posting publicly?

Comment: You cannot be compromised by that information.  You should still remove any information you feel should not be shared of course.  Specfics are often not required to solve problems.

Comment: being honest that's why I asked this question because I don't know "...remove any information you feel should not be shared" which one those are.

Comment: userroge, any confidential information. It depends on the hardware issue, but there is no need to give out your name, username, password, names of files, etc. Just look at what you are posting before you post and make sure that there is nothing private there.

Answer (score 2):

profoundly unlikely. it takes a lot of imagination to imagine how. Like maybe if one of the hardware devices was online like, with an IP and MAC address. but even then it's behind a NAT Router and not initiating any connections. people are posting about hardware problems they have all the time. it's no risk.

if you were developing a nuclear weapon,  or you had a robot at home, perhaps not accessible on the internet, but there was a risk somebody malicious and highly technical might gain access directly, then you wouldn't want to share info online. because if they knew all about it then they may be able to do something to quickly install some controlling software that they'd been writing for a while to control it. So if they knew the hardware info of it, they could write something to make it kill you in the night. But that's a risk if they even see your robot twice. Once to see what model it is, and once to install the malicious software. They'd need direct access to it though, unless the robot likes browsing the internet.